# C Pointer Errors

Tags: c, pointers

I made this program in C and I am getting an error I don't know how to fix. Please help me find the error.
This is the code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int x = 98;
  int *g = x;
  printf("This is x: %d, and this is g: %i.\n", x, *g);
  *g=45;
  printf("This is x: %d, and this is g: %i.\n", x, *g);

  return 0;
}
```

The compiler gives me the following errors:

```
ex15t.c: In function ‘main’:
ex15t.c:5:12: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

Thanks ahead for any help.

Comment: Can you update your description to actually suggest what you're really trying to do? Your code does not clarify at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

currently you are assinging whatever value (98) is in x to the pointer,  and sice an int is not a pointer its warning you.   What you really want is to get the address of where x is, ie, point to the location of x.  So....

```
int *g = x;
```

needs to be

```
int *g = &x;
```

Answer (score 6):

The line: `int * g = x;` is defining variable `g` of type `int *`, and then assigning the value of `x` to it.

Expanded out, this can be read as:

```
int *g;
g = x;
```

and this is obviously not what you want, as `x` is type `int` and `g` is type `int *`.

Assuming that you want `g` to point to the variable `x`, instead do this

```
int * g = &x;
```

or instead do this, which may be clearer:

```
int *g;
g = &x;
```